# Adding touchscreen driver via command line

Tags: command-line, drivers, android, touchscreen

I've installed Android x86 on my windows tablet, and all works apart from the touchscreen. I've found out how to add support to it, but only by using the source, which I don't really know how to, and it would take out WiFi, Ethernet, USB, etc. I was wondering if it is possible to add the support via command line? I think its similar to Ubuntu's commands to install.

Here is the link to the touchscreen patch. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-x86/sqORX7AAICY

I don't know how to install drivers on Ubuntu either, so if somebody could tell me how, I'd appreciate trying it.